# INotifyPropertyChanged for properties that are located in DLL file

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, inotifypropertychanged

For example you have prepared an dll file with some classes in it. Then you want to use this classes in your project. So how can you implement `INotifyProperty` for properties that are located in dll file. I am using MVVM so this classes are like model.

If I change some value I want to update my UI but I can't do it because I can't implement `INotifyProperty` for classes that are located in my dll file. If you ask why I can't implement this interface in my own dll file, I will tell you it's because `INotifyProperty` is specific interface that we use in WPF projects and what if I don't want to use WPF. That is why I prepared one dll file where I wrote some kind of business logic classes.

Comment: Write a WPF notifiable Wrapper over those classes? May be use Partial Classes or Inherit the base non INPC classes into WPF supporting Classes.

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged` is not used just in WPF, not sure why you think that. In WinForms, for example, it's used all the time to bind class objects to a BindingSource, otherwise, no PropertyChanged notifications are received and bound UI elements are not updated.

Comment: yes we can use it in winforms too. but in ASP.NET i think i cant use INotifyPropertyChanged because our view is creating by using html and css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really, I think you should just implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the original class in the dll. Implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` does not prevent you from using non-WPF UIs. You can always implement additional interfaces if other frameworks require something else. Also, just because WPF uses `INotifyPropertyChanged` *does not* mean that it is *only* for WPF; other frameworks might make use of it as well. I can't see any reason why you would want to avoid implementing an interface that you need.

That said, if you *really* don't want to for some reason, the only other thing I can think of would be to create a wrapper class. That would require a lot of duplicate code (e.g. property declarations). Plus that might not even work if you have some properties that automatically update others, or methods that require arguments of the original type.